# dual boot (K)Ubuntu overwritten grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I have been using ubuntu16.04 for a while now, and had grub configured with themes and everything on it, but now i wanted to have another distro alongside it and installed kubuntu16.04.
While installing kubuntu, it also installed a new grub, and when i start my computer, it uses the grub from kubuntu instead of my old grub that was configured on my ubuntu.

How do i change it back?

If you need aditional info, just ask.

thanks in advance,
Bart

Comment: Try to  run `sudo update-grub2` from a terminal in your in your old Ubuntu installation to install that version of GRUB again.

Comment: In addition to the command given by @SorenA you have to reinstall the boot loader from within Ubuntu with `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` ( change `sda` with your correct drive-letter). Then boot to Kubuntu and purge Grub in Kubuntu with `sudo apt purge grub*`. While purging Grub you should get a warning that the OS might be not bootable, you can ignore this warning as you need Grub installed in only one of your installed distributions.

Comment: if one of you can have this as an answer, i can tag it as an answer.